# How to make sure all messages are published before calling ros::Publisher::shutdown?

Tags: ros, roscpp, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my C++ program I publish a message to a ros::Publisher with the publish method and then immediately shuts down the publisher using the shutdown method (because the program is finished). However, the result is that the message is not published. If I add a sleep of a few milliseconds before the shutdown, then it works. My question is, how do I make sure that all messages waiting in the publisher's queue are sent before calling shutdown?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52429/how-to-make-sure-all-messages-are-published-before-calling-ros::publisher::shutdown?/) by [fredrik.heintz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3976/fredrik.heintz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fredrik.heintz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3976/fredrik.heintz/) on 2013-01-15**:
I tried explicitly calling the processPublishQueue on the publication associated with the topic after publish and before shutdown:
ros::PublicationPtr pub = ros::TopicManager::instance()->lookupPublication(topic_name);
if (pub) {
pub->processPublishQueue();
}
But it didn't send the message.

**Comment by [fredrik.heintz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3976/fredrik.heintz/) on 2013-01-15**:
Adding a cout statement or sleep(1000) however works fine, but it seems very risky to rely on this to make sure the message is actually sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The standard solution is to wait before shutting down. If you want a communication channel with known delivery you need to use a service call.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0